# How to draw a table using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of football matches in la liga and I want to make a table where each row and column is a team name and each tile shows what the result was in the game between the two teams of row and column

I've tried many using `geom_tile` and `ggplot2` in many different ways but the closest I've come to is the below code

```
library(dplyr)
library(engsoccerdata)
spain = as.data.frame(spain)
library(ggplot2)
game1 = filter(spain, Season == "2012")
ggplot(game1, aes(home, reorder(visitor,desc(visitor)), fill = FT)) + 
  geom_tile(color="white", size=1.5, stat="identity", height=1, width=1) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = rep(c("blue","white"),30)) +
  geom_text(data=game1, aes(home, visitor, label = FT), size=rel(3)) +
  scale_x_discrete(position="top") + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  xlab("Home") + ylab("Visitor") +
  ggtitle("Laliga 2012")
```

I need the rows to be colored by oddity (odd rows white and even rows blue)
Also I want the team names to be inside tiles
over all I want my table to look like the first photo [here](http://rforjournalists.com/2016/09/24/creating-premier-league-results-matrix-in-r/) but with striped lines

can anyone help me on modifications to my code?

Comment: Hi, please could you eventually provide example data by using `dput()`? Thanks! [(*More...*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038)

Comment: @jaySf here's a [link](https://github.com/jalapic/engsoccerdata/blob/master/data/spain.rda) to the dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the row-colors by specifying a new factor just for fill. Consider e.g. this

```
fillframe = as.numeric(reorder(game1$visitor,desc(game1$visitor)))
fillframe = as.factor(ifelse(fillframe %% 2 == 0, 1, 0))

ggplot(game1, aes(home, reorder(visitor,desc(visitor)), fill = fillframe)) + 
  geom_tile(color="white", size=1.5, stat="identity", height=1, width=1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "lightblue")) +
  geom_text(data=game1, aes(home, visitor, label = FT), size=rel(3)) +
  scale_x_discrete(position="top") + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  xlab("Home") + ylab("Visitor") +
  ggtitle("Laliga 2012") +
  theme(legend.position = "None",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 315))
```

[image]

For including the axis labels in the tiles, you'd have to expand the axis (since it is categorical, again by specifying additional factors), think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856318/colour-axis-labels-or-draw-rectangles-over-axis-in-ggplot2) - but then you'd be better off just using Rmarkdown or HTML or so

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my problem was I couldn't figure out the fillframe part. when I run the modified code the text from x axis on top gets into the table is there a way to solve that too?

Comment: You could try changing the `angle` argument in the theme part, for example `axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)`

Comment: For passerby, angle = 315 for a similar effect in most recent versions of ggplot2